# How to animate when switching CALayers

Tags: ios, objective-c, calayer

I'm adding and removing `CALayers` using this method :

```
[[[self.view.layer sublayers] objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperlayer];
    if(++self.backgroundIndex > self.gradients.count - 1) {
        self.backgroundIndex = 0;
    }
    CAGradientLayer *layer = [self.gradients objectAtIndex:self.backgroundIndex];
    layer.frame = self.view.frame;
    [self.view.layer insertSublayer:layer atIndex:0];
```

How can I animate this ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Core Animation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/CreatingBasicAnimations/CreatingBasicAnimations.html) when adding and removing `CALayers` something like this

```
CABasicAnimation *fadeOut = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
fadeOut.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
fadeOut.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
fadeOut.duration = 1.0;        // 1 second

[[[self.view.layer sublayers] objectAtIndex:0] addAnimation:fadeOut forKey:@"fadeOutAnimation"];
```

//Adding Layer animation

```
CAGradientLayer *layer = [self.gradients objectAtIndex:self.backgroundIndex];

CABasicAnimation *fadeIn = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
fadeIn.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
fadeIn.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
fadeIn.duration = 1.0;        // 1 second

[layer addAnimation:fadeIn forKey:@"fadeInAnimation"];
```